# Check if current page is category page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to insert some condition if the current page is a category page or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found the way to do it by checking if `$cat_id` is available or not on that page by the following.

```
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
```

Now we can check if $cat_id is available then it is a category page otherwise it is not.

Comment: Is this one line of code all you need? Should there be an if statement and condition after that?

Comment: @AK It ha been explained that there should be condition to check.

Comment: mentioned ≠ explained

Answer (score 17):

you can use this for getting category

```
is_category();
is_category( '1' ); // where 1 is category id
is_category( 'test' ); // where test is category name
is_category( 'test-ing' ); // where test-ing is category slug
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
is_category();
```

function.

refrence:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category

Comment: Thanks @Yatendra!  I have tried that function but I couldn't differentiate the page is post page or category page.

Comment: Same here - no success with that method.

Answer (score 2):

Amit's answer will work but there is a simpler way as Wordpress sets a Global var for the category id of $cat. So just checking if this is set will tell you if you are on a category page.

```
if(!empty($cat)){ //do something just on a category archive page }
```