# I am trying to change the image depending on the category page the user is on

Tags: php, html, wordpress

***Please only answer if you're going to take the time to read and try to understand the question.***

The image below is an example of the category page... The item I want to change depending on the category the user is on is the ***Pink Background 'Store Content' image***. Basically I want to make it dynamic to change to another image when on the appropriate category page... I'm just not sure how to do it...

[image]

```
<?php /* Start of Shop Header */ ?>

    <?php if (is_category('Technology')) : ?>

    <div class="container gridlove-ad-below-header round_corners">
        <div class="gridlove-ad">
    <style>
        .top_home_page { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
        @media(min-width: 500px) { .top_home_page { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
        @media(min-width: 800px) { .top_home_page { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
        .round_corners { border-radius: 5px !important;}
    </style>

        <img class="round_corners hover-shadow" src="https://staging-dapulse.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Store-Content.jpg"/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php elseif (is_category('News', 'Science')) : ?>
        <h5>No store image goes here</h5>
        <?php else : ?>
        <p>This is some generic text to describe all other category pages, 
        I could be left blank</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php /* End of Shop Header */ ?>
```

Comment: add image to category image pragmatically or using plugin, plugin not recommended then in your category page call the thumbnail of that category. It will be dynamic.

Comment: This is a wordpress theme... The category page uses the index.php file... all changes to the index.php file would reflect on all the category pages. The code sample above works... but only for 1 image... I want to know how I can add more for the categories where I do want it to show.

Comment: can you please try the below code

Answer (score 0):

**please try the following code**

```
 if ( is_product_category() ){  
            global $wp_query;
            $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
            $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
            if ( $image ) {
                echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $cat->name . '" />';
            }
            else{
                //your default image if category have't any image
                $static_image = 'static image path';
                echo '<img src="' . $static_image . '" />';
            }
        }
```

Comment: How would I apply the image?

Comment: @AlejandroM where did you add the category images?have you tried to paste this code in your hedaer.php file ?

Comment: @AlejandroM are you add image on this path wp-admin=product(menu)->category->upload thumbnail am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use category image plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-taxonomy-image/ or https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-featured-image/

Once install you will have to rewrite the code to be something like this.

1. Because as you say it use `index.php` and you want to only show image on category page then you should first check if its category page may be using this procedure https://stackoverflow.com/a/19558546/507203
2. If its category page then you get the category_id/term_id and query for the category image. Look info how to query for image from the plugin you installed.
3. Echo out the image and you are done.

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution elsewhere... wish it could be shortened... but unfortunately I have to paste it 6 times for each category.

***If someone could help me shorten this I'd appreciate it...***

```
<?php if (is_category( 'News' )) : ?><img class="round_corners hover-shadow" src="https://staging-dapulse.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Store-Content-News.jpg"/><?php endif;?>

<?php if (is_category( 'Technology' )) : ?><img class="round_corners hover-shadow" src="https://staging-dapulse.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Store-Content-Technology.jpg"/><?php endif;?>

<?php if (is_category( 'Entertainment' )) : ?><img class="round_corners hover-shadow" src="https://staging-dapulse.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Store-Content-Entertainment.jpg"/><?php endif;?>

<?php if (is_category( 'Science' )) : ?><img class="round_corners hover-shadow" src="https://staging-dapulse.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Store-Content-Science.jpg"/><?php endif;?>

<?php if (is_category( 'Lifestyle' )) : ?><img class="round_corners hover-shadow" src="https://staging-dapulse.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Store-Content-Lifestyle.jpg"/><?php endif;?>

<?php if (is_category( 'Business' )) : ?><img class="round_corners hover-shadow" src="https://staging-dapulse.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Store-Content-Business.jpg"/><?php endif;?>
```

Comment: it's not a solution what about when you add new category ?

Comment: have you tried my code ? it's perfectly work for you with a single query

Comment: I want to pull the image from the media library... I can't assign images to categories as how WordPress is set up

Comment: use switch case instead of if condition.

Comment: switch case? I'm new to php